# How to change Simulator Test Parallelization in Xcode on XCode13

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, apple-m1, xcode13

Within XCode 13 > Preferences > General, I am trying to change the number of Simulators to be used for my tests.  It keeps resetting it back to Auto once I switch tabs or close the dialog and come back.  I tried rebooting my machine and trying again but it is still resetting it after I adjust it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A workaround:
Quit XCode. In ~/Library/Preferences, there is a file called "com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist".  You can edit the values for the following two Keys: IDEMaxParallelTestingWorkersMac, IDEMaxParallelTestingSimulators.  Restart XCode.